# How detect format of date field in form alter?

Tags: datetime

How can I find if a form has date/time field or not and if it has, how can I detect what is **date format** for it?

Answer (score 1):

For the Date popup selector, the `#date_format` element in the form element. For example:

```
    //The date field has the format of "d-m-Y"
    $form['date_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'date_select',
      '#title' => t('My Date'),
      '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
      '#date_label_position' => 'within',
      '#date_year_range' => '0:+1',
      '#description' => t('This is a test date picker'),
      '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
```

There's an D6 [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/292667) on d.o, but it's still valid for D7 last I looked.

Comment: this code works when you want to add a new field to a form. I mean when in form_alter between available fields, how we can detect which fields are datetime and how we can detect what is date format for each of them.
indeed I want to manipulate datetime fields in output render.